# What is the difference between a Sephardic and Ashkenaz eruv?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, eruv-chatzerot

Here in Staten Island, we supposedly have an Eruv. However, when I asked my Sefardi rabbi on whether we can use it or not, he said we can't.

Any details about what would make an Ashkenaz eruv pasul for Sepharadim?

Clarification- We follow Hacham Ovadia Yosef.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a difference in construction. The difference is that Sepharadim (traditionally) do not accept communal 'Eruvin in large cities/neighborhoods, due to the position of the Mehaber (Shulhan 'Aruch [O"H 345:7](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Orach_Chaim/345)) that defines* a public domain by size, not by population density. <strike>Some</strike> Many Sepharadim have accepted the Ashkenazi leniency in following the population density, but it's possible that either your rabbi does not follow that leniency or that your community does not fit within the acceptable norms for that leniency.

More details about the community in question would help *our* community to form a better answer.

<sub>*Please note that there are several criteria, but I'm focusing on the main sticking point.</sub>

Comment: Got a citation from the S"A? (and/or MB that opposes it?)

Comment: Seems the Rama doesn't argue. What makes you think it's a Sefardi/Ashkenazi thing?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's not, strictly speaking, but Sepharadim are more uniformly against it, and Ashkenazim are more generally supportive of it.

Comment: Mishnah Berurah (ad loc. 23): (כג) וי"א שכל שאין ששים רבוא וכו' - סבירא להו דגם לזה בעינן דומיא דדגלי מדבר שהיו ששים רבוא ואף שהיה שם עוד ערב רב ונשים וטף לא חשבינן אלא מה שנמצא בכתוב בפירוש. ולענין הלכה מדעת המחבר דכתב דעה זו רק בשם י"א משמע דלהלכה לא ס"ל כן ומ"מ אין בנו כח למחות ביד הסומכין על דעה זו דדעה זו ג"כ לא דעת יחידאה היא כמו שכתבתי בביאור הלכה וכן צדדו כמה אחרונים וכל בעל נפש יחמיר לעצמו ועיין בסימן שס"ד במשנה ברורה סק"ז ובביאור הלכה כאן ושם:

Answer (score 1):

One major point that comes up is Rambam's opinion that each *tzuras hapesach* -- archway -- can be no wider than 16 Amos (~24 feet). So you'd need posts every 24 feet; that's much harder to set up. (I believe Lubavitchers follow this Rambam as well.)

Comment: I think you're confusing a couple different opinions here.

Comment: Rambam also allows more than 16 amot between poles if more than half of the eruv is solid wall.